# difference between webpack 4 Hot Module Replacement and react-hot-loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr, react-hot-loader

Implementing Hot Module Repacement using [webpack 4](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/#enabling-hmr) example works perfectly, and my react component are rendering smoothly as well.

However in the webpack documentation at the end, there is mentioning of [react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader).

**Can any one explain the difference in HMR in webpack4 and HMR implemented using react-hot-loader ? Is there any difference when implementing react redux**

Comment: https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/08/blogged-answers-webpack-hmr-vs-rhl/ maybe this article can help you